# Unintuitive case in finding loop in linked list

Tags: algorithms

Finding a loop in a linked list is a classic algorithm but I found an off-by one case that is making me question my sanity, this first solution works:

```python
def findLoop(head):
    def p(s, f):
        print(f'slow: {s.value}, fast: {f.value}')
        
    slow = head.next
    fast = head.next.next
    
    while slow is not fast:
        p(slow, fast)
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next

    p(slow, fast)
    slow = head
    while slow is not fast:
        p(slow, fast)
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next 
    return slow
```

This second one goes into an infinite loop since on the second while loop, the pointers never meet:

```python
def findLoop(head):
    def p(s, f):
        print(f'slow: {s.value}, fast: {f.value}')
        
    slow = head
    fast = head.next
    
    while slow is not fast:
        p(slow, fast)
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next

    p(slow, fast)
    slow = head
    while slow is not fast:
        p(slow, fast)
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next 
    return slow
```

Note that all that changed is the starting conditions: in the working solution we have `slow = head.next; fast = head.next.next`; while in the breaking solution we have: `slow = head; fast = head.next`. This change should not have a breaking effect and even though I can walk through it by had, I don't understand why it should happen, given that we only shift the starting conditions by one.

**Supplementary Material**

Ready to run example for experimenting:

```python
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

def findLoop(head):
    def p(s, f):
        print(f'slow: {s.value}, fast: {f.value}')
        
    slow = head.next
    fast = head.next.next
    
    while slow is not fast:
        p(slow, fast)
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next

    p(slow, fast)
    slow = head
    while slow is not fast:
        p(slow, fast)
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next 
    return slow
    
case =  [
      {"id": "0", "next": "1", "value": 0},
      {"id": "1", "next": "2", "value": 1},
      {"id": "2", "next": "3", "value": 2},
      {"id": "3", "next": "4", "value": 3},
      {"id": "4", "next": "5", "value": 4},
      {"id": "5", "next": "6", "value": 5},
      {"id": "6", "next": "7", "value": 6},
      {"id": "7", "next": "8", "value": 7},
      {"id": "8", "next": "9", "value": 8},
      {"id": "9", "next": "4", "value": 9}
    ]

def create(case):
    for c in case:
        c['node'] = LinkedList(c['value'])
    for c in case:
        c['node'].next = case[int(c['next'])]['node']     
    return case[0]['node']

def test():
    head = create(case)
    findLoop(head)

test()
```

Comment: When you say it "should not have a breaking effect", I suggest you take this as an indication that your intuition about what should and shouldn't matter isn't 100% correct in this situation.  You already know of a counterexample, which already demonstrates that one version doesn't work, so it's not clear what kind of "why" answer you're hoping for.  Have you tried constructing a proof of correctness for the correct algorithm, then seeing what breaks down when you try to apply it to the wrong algorithm?  That is sometimes one helpful way to get a better sense of "why" it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am delighted to see another example of the infamous off-by-one error.

---

"All that changed is the starting conditions". "This change should not have a breaking effect" since "we only shift the starting conditions by one." Well, as D.W. implied in his comment, that change does have a breaking effect!

With that shifting change, the node where `slow` and `fast` meet at the end of first `while` in the right version of `findLoop` is not the same as that in the wrong version of `findLoop`. In fact, they meet one node earlier in the wrong version than in the correction version. That means, the distance between `head` and `fast` at the end of the first `while` in the wrong version is one less than that distance in the right version. Since `slow` is reset to `head` before the start of the second `while` in both version, the distance between `slow` and `fast` at the start of the second `while` in the wrong version is one less than that distance in the right version.

For the second `while` to end, the distance between `slow` and `fast` must be a multiple of the period of the loop of the linked list. So the second `while` will go forever in the wrong version of `findLoop`, as long as the period is not $1$.

---

**Exercise** (easy): Assume that there is a loop in the linked list and that `head.next != head.next.next`. Explain why the node where `slow` and `fast` meet at the end of first `while` in the wrong version of `findLoop` is one node earlier than that node in the correction version, i.e. the next node of the former node is the latter node.

Comment: > "For the second while loop to end, the distance between slow and fast must be a multiple of the period" -- this is warm enough for me to look into and appreciate. Thank you very much.